# C program not passing values to method

Tags: c, methods

I'm working on a homework assignment, and I've run into something strange. I've got three files: Lab3.c, Lab3.h, and driver.c. driver.c is calling a method from Lab3.c, and failing to pass values into the method.

```
// code from driver.c
float cyRad, cyHt;
printf("Enter a radius for the cylinder: ");
scanf("%f", &cyRad);
printf("%f\n", cyRad);
printf("Enter a height for the cylinder: ");
scanf("%f", &cyHt);
float cyVol = cylinder(cyRad, cyHt);
printf("Cylinder volume: %f\n", cyVol);

// code from Lab3.c
float cylinder(float radius, float height) 
{
    printf("%f %f %f\n", M_PI, height, radius);
    return M_PI * height * pow(radius, 2);
}

// code from Lab3.h
#ifndef __LAB3_H
#define __LAB3_H

extern void sphere(float radius, float *surface, float *volume);
extern float volCylinder(float radius, float height);
extern double sumFloats(double x[], int numFloats);
extern double sine(float angle);

#endif
```

And here's the output:

```
Enter a radius for the cylinder: 13
13.000000
Enter a height for the cylinder: 45
3.141593 0.000000 0.000000
Cylinder volume: 0.000000
```

I have no idea why it's not passing the values into the method `cylinder`. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If `M_PI` does not have a `f` at the end of its literal definition, you should use `%lf` for it.

Comment: everything goes well on vs2012.

Comment: I changed it, recompiled, and ran it again with `%lf`. Didn't seem to make any difference. I'm using M_PI from the `math` library, by the way. Dunno if that changes things.

Comment: @gongzhitaao Hmm. Thanks for testing it for me. I'm working off of Linux, using `gcc`. Would that make a difference?

Comment: So far as I could tell, no difference.

Comment: @Chance... I just tried it in the same file using `gcc` i.e. `MinGW` and it works fine. One question. Can you confirm if the function `cylinder` defined as an `extern`?

Comment: Where do you declare those tow ``float``s and where do you use them? Do a ``printf`` before passing to ``cylinder``.

Comment: @Chance.. I tried `cylinder` function defined in a different file and accessed as `extern` in main file. Still works for me ..

Comment: @chris: in a `printf()`, `%f` processes a `double` because of default argument promotion in variable length argument lists.

Comment: @Chance: you've not checked that the `scanf()` calls worked, and you've not printed out the values they read.  However, there's no obvious reason why the entered values would cause trouble.

Comment: The function `cylinder` is defined as `extern` in Lab3.h. I'll throw the code for that into the question as well.

Comment: You also need to show where you #include Lab3.h relative to the code that calls cylinder. You should always post a SSCCE -- http://sscce.org/

Comment: There's a function `volCylinder()` in `Lab3.h`; there isn't a function `cylinder()`.  Isn't your compiler warning you that you're calling a function without a prototype?  It should be — or you should tweak its options until it does — or get a better compiler.  Given that you've not declared `cylinder()`, the `float` arguments are being promoted to `double` in the call, and the return type is assumed to be `int`.  All of which leads to the mess you're seeing.

Comment: Is this function `extern float volCylinder(float radius, float height);` same as `cylinder` because both the function names are different?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I checked the `scanf()` for `cyRad`, and it worked. I checked the values after the call from inside the method, and they received 0's.

Comment: ... Ah, hell, did I not change the function name in Lab3.h? One second.

Comment: Son of a gun, I'm quite stupid. Thank you, @Ganesh, I changed the name everywhere except inside the .h.

Comment: @Chance.. Welcome.. Copy paste is always dangerous if not done with care :)

Comment: @Chance It's not stupidity, it's an easy mistake to make. Since we're human, we need tools ... do yourself a big favor and follow Jonathan's advice ... the compiler should have warned you about this.

Comment: @Ganesh This isn't copy/paste, it's the opposite ... incomplete refactoring. These days many professional programmers use IDEs that do the refactoring for them so these errors don't arise.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Maybe I was thinking of `long double` vs those two instead of `float` vs the others >.>

Comment: @chris: In `scanf()` et al, the difference between `%f` and `%lf` is crucial (`float *` vs `double *`); in `printf()` in C89, `%lf` wasn't defined; in C99, it is formally the same as `%f` for consistency with `scanf()` et al.  The length modifier for `long double` is `L` for both `printf()` and `scanf()`, of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Ah, right. This is what I get for relying on my memory when I've barely ever used `printf`, let alone `scanf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a prototype in scope when you call a function, otherwise it is assumed to return `int` and its argument types are unknown. When passing floats to a function with unknown argument types, they are passed as doubles, which will result in bogus values in the function (the behavior is undefined, so theoretically anything could happen, though what does actually happen depends on the implementation, but it won't be what you want).

The best way to go about having declarations in scope in multi-file programs is to have a .h file for every .c file; the .h file declares the functions (and other globals) defined in the .c file. Then #include the .h file into any file that uses those globals ... including the companion .c file.

Comment: A method prototype? Shouldn't that be handled by the Lab3.h file?

Comment: @Chance ... That's what I said ... there should be a Lab3.h file to accompany Lab3.c and it should be included into driver.c ... if you're doing that, you haven't shown it ... please provide all relevant code.

Comment: Now now, you only had the first paragraph of that answer posted when I responded. I'll post up the code for `Lab3.h`.

Comment: You were right, I forgot to change the name of the method in the .h file.

Comment: @Chance Your comment didn't appear until some time after I made my edit. Regardless, the fact is that you don't have a prototype for `cylinder` in scope.